# Cisco Switch 3500 Default settings

Tags: cisco, switch

I need to erase all the settings on our old Cisco switches. I have already logged into (`enable-mode` after password reset). Now I'm not sure what exactly I need to erase in the (dir) I noticed there is the config.text/vlan.dat files....Do I need to remove those? When I "more" command the config.text file it shows a lot of ip,vlan,etc data that looks like it should be removed before we get rid of these.

Comment: Do you already know the command `write erase`?

Comment: Also use 'del vlan.dat' to delete the vlan database

Comment: radicetrentasei and James' input is correct (after a reload)... please let us know if you have more issues

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Also, be sure to delete the `vlan.dat` file on the switch and reload before placing on a live, critical network. Keeping this old file will cause some serious network outages :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the command

> Erase start-upconfig

The command returns all your settings to the factory default (in your startup-config). The only thing you have to do after that is a reload. Then when the reload is complete you'll have the default settings.

Comment: That does not actually erase the `vlan.dat` file that holds all the VLAN information, and the VLANs will reappear.